# writing to excel sheet in robot framework

Tags: python, excel, robotframework, data-driven-tests

I have test cases in robot framework.
Scenario is data driven scenario from excel
for example ;
I have 2 column; First column is full that from my data

| rezno | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| resno 1 |  |
| resno 2 |  |

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary
Library     BuiltIn
Resource   ../../StepDefinition/Operation/OperationSteps.robot
Library     DataDriver      ../../Locator/Operation/testdata3.xls        sheet_name: sheet1
Test Teardown   Terminate Test Cases
Test Template   TEST IADE


*** Test Cases ***
Input ${RezNo}

*** Keywords ***
TEST IADE
    [Arguments]     ${RezNo}
    User goes to home page
    User fills username textbox with "xxxx"
    User fills password textbox with "xxxx"
    User clicks to login button
    User clicks to Read and Confirm button
    User fills to "${RezNo}" reservation number on searchbar
    User clicks to search button
    User get text from search result
   
How should i write column b in per run suite excel file
it think its kind of must be iteration

Anyone know that ? can u suggest me ?  
      




i tried excellibrary but not working in step
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Excel library given by Robocorp.
Install
pip install rpaframework

Check for more keywords: https://rpaframework.org/libraries/excel_files/index.html

```
*** Settings ***
Library    RPA.Excel.Files

*** Test Cases ***
Creating new Excel
    Create Workbook  ${EXECDIR}\\testdata\\Amount.xlsx
    FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    20
        &{row}=       Create Dictionary    Row No=${index}    Amount=${index * 25}
        Append Rows to Worksheet  ${row}  header=${TRUE}
    END
    Save Workbook
    

Edit Excel
    Open Workbook    ${EXECDIR}\\testdata\\OpenEMRData.xlsx  
    ${sheet}        Read Worksheet   Sheet1
    Set Worksheet Value    1    1    Balaji    
    Save Workbook    
    Close Workbook
```